# Adding additional NPM packages to a yo angular generated project

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've noticed that yo angular generates a GruntFile containing all of the instructions, but typically does not include `grunt.loadNpmTasks('<package>')` statements, which may or may not be indicative of globally installed packages (?).

So, what is the correct way to add additional NPM packages to a yo-angular generated project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the yo angular generator uses [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks), which prevents the gruntfile from becoming to bloated:

> This module will read the
>   dependencies/devDependencies/peerDependencies in your package.json and
>   load grunt tasks that match the provided patterns.

the generator uses [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks) without a pattern provided

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
```

which means that it will simply try to load everything (with the pattern `grunt-*`, for more info see comments below) you install via npm.

long story short, just `npm install` it (grunt tasks should be installed with the `--save-dev` option, to automatically move it to the devDependencies)

```
$ npm install your-grunt-task --save-dev
```

Comment: I believe the default pattern is `grunt-`?

Comment: `var pattern = arrayify(options.pattern || ['grunt-*']);` so the default pattern is `grunt-*`

Comment: That means it won't load everything installed via npm, just grunt plugins.

Comment: yes, it loads only plugins who's **name** starts with `grunt-` which usually should be grunt-plugins. i dont know about any plugins not starting with `grunt-`, or any non-grunt-plugins starting with `grunt-`

Comment: You said that it will load everything installed with npm, non-grunt packages can also be installed with npm, so it won’t load those. I suggested that instead of “everything” you say “all grunt plugins”.